# Unix: how to open a new tcsh and keep the aliases

Tags: shell, unix, alias, csh, tcsh

I have a usage in which I have to open a new `tcsh`. I want the aliases set on the current shell to be available also in the new `tcsh` shell.
It is not done by default and I wanted to know if there's a way to let it work...

Here's how my problem looks:

```
> alias hello pwd
> hello
/home/user123
> tcsh
> hello
hello: Command not found.
```

** Edit **

I just wanted to clarify that I don't want to add the aliases to `~/.aliases`, as they should be defined in a  specific shell, and not in any new shell I open. I want them to be "inherited" like environment variables.

Is it possible anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the sense of starting a new process but wanting the state of another one (without explicit IPC as shared memory, etc.)?

Comment: I try to open an xterm window with commands, and then want it to be interactive. So, the common solution I found for making such xterm interactive is to add "tcsh" command at the end (makes sence). But then, the aliases created by the previous commands I passed to the xterm are lost

Comment: I don't think it is possible out of the box.  You could always get a list of current aliases (using 'alias' by itself) and write them to a temporary file, and read them in again in the new shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering here with @Mark_Armstrong comment.

It is possible to use the command `alias` to print all the available aliases, and to save them into a file.

Then you can use some scripting to add a preceding "alias " string to each line in that file, and to "source" it.

Or you can just iterate over the file lines using `csh` and run `alias $line`